# Is it required to free the memory even when process is being terminated?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I have a doubt with respect to freeing the memory allocated within a process. If I have allocated a memory in the process and the process is being terminated, is it still required to free the memory? If not freed, is it akin to memory leak?

Because once the process is killed/terminated its Virtual Address Space also no longer exists.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a good habit to take care of anything you created and you should take the responsibility of it,though the system would free everything you ever used in your program when it was terminated in the case you proposed.